# How to solve this simple Algebraic equation? (Wolfram & SymboLab both stumped...)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I need to solve the following equation for a hobby coding project I'm working on and I can't figure out the solution. Wolfram and SymboLab solvers are both stumped.

$$0 = d - (r^{p-1} * (p-1) * c)$$

I'm trying to solve for $p$, where $d$, $r$, $c$, and $p$ are all positive real numbers.

Seems like it should be quite doable. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Since it’s numerical, just use Newton’s method.

Answer (score 5):

I may have a solution. The bad news: you're not going to like it because it's nasty. It ain't pretty.

So first, we get all of the $p$-based terms on one side of the equation, probably the most trivial step. This is kosher since all of the constants are nonzero. This gives us

$$(p-1)r^{(p-1)} = \frac{d}{c}$$

*This* is where it goes downhill. For simplicity, I let $x = p-1$ to make this a *bit* prettier, and we reduce this problem to finding $x$:

$$xr^{x} = \frac{d}{c}$$

If you've ever heard of the Lambert $W$-function, this expression absolutely screams its use. If not, the $W$ function is essentially introduced in scenarios where we have $xe^x = c$ for some number $c$ and want to find $x$. Then the $W$ function is applied to both sides to give $x = W(c)$. The $W$ function is basically the "inverse" to $xe^x$, i.e. $W(xe^x) = x$. I'll be honest and admit I don't know a *whole* lot about it, so I'll link to [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

The article does give us a way to solve $xr^x$ when $r$ is not necessarily $e$: the identity that

$$z = xa^x \;\;\; \Leftrightarrow \;\;\; x = \frac{W(z \ln(a))}{\ln(a)}$$

Take $z = d/c, a = r.$ Then,

$$\frac{d}{c} = xr^x \;\;\; \Leftrightarrow \;\;\; x = \frac{1}{\ln(r)}W\left(\frac{d}{c} \cdot \ln(r) \right)$$

Then, since $x = p-1,$

$$p = 1 + \frac{1}{\ln(r)}W\left(\frac{d}{c} \cdot \ln(r) \right)$$

Per the Wikipedia article, "the Lambert W relation cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions," so unless there's a method I overlooked in solving this, this might be the best you get.

I'm not sure how it would be evaluated. The Wikipedia article notes some special values and approximation via Newton's method.

Comment: There are many articles and papers published on approximations of $W_0$ (the principal branch). Else, the OP can consider using Newton's method for example to find roots of the inverse of $xe^x$.

Comment: Lambert function is beautiful ! So many applications in so many areas. If you serach for *"Lambert"* in this site, you will find 2550 entries.